# Multi-Threading Implementation

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to implement multi-threading for data scraping.

DATA_TABLE is a oracle sql table containing serial_number, Link_URL and Link_Status columns.

Serial_number: To track the number of entries in the table.

Link_URL : URL to be scraped.

Link_Status: 0 = not scraped & 1 = scraped.

**Code**:

```
import os
import boto3
import cx_Oracle
import logging
import configparser
from trafilatura import fetch_url, extract
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# Load configuration from the config.ini file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

oracle_username = config.get('database', 'username')
oracle_password = config.get('database', 'password')
oracle_host = config.get('database', 'host')
oracle_port = config.get('database', 'port')
oracle_service_name = config.get('database', 'service_name')

# Create a connection pool to ensure each thread has its own separate connection
pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(
    user=oracle_username,
    password=oracle_password,
    dsn=f"{oracle_host}:{oracle_port}/{oracle_service_name}",
    min=2,
    max=4,
    increment=1,
    threaded=True
)

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

bucket_name = config.get('S3', 's3_bucket_name')
folder_path = config.get('S3', 's3_folder_path_test')

def fetch_url_and_process(link_url, serial_number):
    try:
        connection = pool.acquire()
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Scrap the text from the URL using trafilature
            downloaded = fetch_url(link_url)
            extracted_text = extract(downloaded)

            print('******************************************')
            print(extracted_text)
            print('******************************************')

            if extracted_text is None:
                extracted_text = 'delete'

            # Save the extracted text to a text file
            local_file_name = f'{serial_number}.txt'
            print('--------------------------->', local_file_name)
            with open(local_file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                file.write(extracted_text)

            # Upload the text file to S3 bucket
            s3_client.upload_file(local_file_name, bucket_name, f'{folder_path}{local_file_name}')
            print("Text file uploaded to S3")

            # Delete the local text file
            os.remove(local_file_name)

            # Update Link_Status to 1
            update_query = "UPDATE DATA_TABLE SET Link_Status = 1 WHERE Link_URL = :url"
            cursor.execute(update_query, {'url': link_url})
            connection.commit()

    except cx_Oracle.Error as e:
        logging.error(f"Error while inserting data into Oracle: {e}")
    finally:
        pool.release(connection)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        connection = pool.acquire()
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Fetch all Link_URLs where Link_Status = 0
            query = "SELECT Link_URL, Serial_Number FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE Link_Status = 0"
            cursor.execute(query)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            if rows:
                links_to_process = [(row[0], row[1]) for row in rows]

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            executor.map(fetch_url_and_process, links_to_process)
    except cx_Oracle.Error as e:
        logging.error(f"Error while fetching data from Oracle: {e}")
    finally:
        pool.release(connection)
```

Issue: When above is run, the console just prints '**Killed**' after 10-15 mins and execution is terminated. Nothing is printed on the console or log file.
is this the correct way to implement multi-threading for above task?

Comment: `executor.map(...)` returns an [_iterator_](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator). Your program discards the iterator without ever calling its `__next__` method. The [documentation for the `map` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#executor-objects) is unclear about what will happen in that case. It does _not_ forbid `map` from returning before your `fetch_url_and_process` function has been applied to all of the `links_to_process`, and when `map` _does_ return, the next thing your main thread does is call `pool.release(...)`. That might be a problem.

Comment: Run the code in a debugger. For a good question here, it would help to reduce the complexity to a [mcve]. Having a DB with unknown content, S3 plus whatever hosts are involved in the scraping are too many possible sources of problems.

Comment: [Selecting from an Oracle Database table in parallel using Python](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/selecting-from-an-oracle-database-table-in-parallel-using-python-31ecaa2c28c8) may be of interest

Comment: @SolomonSlow , I removed 'pool.release(...)' and also used fetchmany(1000) instead of fetchall() to avoid any memory issue. Now, when I run the code, it just terminate almost instantly without any error and not performing what it is expected to do. 

If I remove the multi-threading part, code is working as expected.

Comment: I have experimented with `ThreadPoolExecutor.map()` on my own computer, and it clearly behaves in a different way from which its documentation led me to expect. I will not attempt to answer your question because clearly, I am not an expert on the subject.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. Please feel free to add...